# How can I attack move my Yorick/Mordekaiser's ghost

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that when I press <kbd>A</kbd> **my champ** does the attack move.

If I press <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd>+click, I only move **my ghost** where my mouse is pointing. But in teamfights, when I want my ghost to attack an enemy, there are sometimes when I misclick the enemy, and the ghost only walks near that champ. Instead...

Is there a way to attack move your ghost?

Comment: I don't have much experience with Yorick, but I do have some with Annie. Tibber's can also be manually controlled with **R**, but if I misclick on accident he'll stand there until I do it again  (and not misclick) or he'll start attacking whatever I start to attack.

Comment: If you move your ghost with R or Alt, he will move to the designated location and start attacking things there (whichever is closest).

Comment: @SirKsilem Your ghost is most likely a ranged AD carry who shouldn't get too close to its target.

Comment: @Aeronth Possibly, but it will also work the same for the AD carry ghost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

Ghosts are controllable pet minions (like Tibbers), and the only way to interact with them (besides moving them) is, as you noticed, to designate a target with <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click.

More information on: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Pet

Comment: So yeah, if definitively there's no way but to aim the target properly, I just have to get used to it even if I'm nervous. :/

Comment: I just realized (didn't test yet), would it work with [A + Alt  + left click]?